# Transcontinental minerals inc

Tags: stocks, shares, share-certificate, ticker-symbols

Transcontinental minerals inc..I have 2 capital stocks certificates from 1994 and have paper from the companys my grandfather gave them to my sister and i but cant find anything on them theres 9000 shares and he bought them at .23. Can anyone help me.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Note that if the shares were moved into electronic form at some point, the certificate may be nothing more than a pretty piece of paper. I still have a certificate for shares I did that with (and solid off long ago).

Comment: @keshlam TCL.A/B on the TSX is not a minerals company.

Comment: They describe themselves as a chemicals and minerals packaging company. But my answer may be a better match. Same websearch.

Comment: This company is based out of colorado

Answer (score 1):

Websearchturns up references like https://www.texas-drilling.com/operators/transcontinental-minerals-corp/864448. That gives address but not ticker symbol.